# Reaching button in title bar in subactivities

Tags: android, tabactivity, titlebar

When creating a titlebar with a button, which is common in all activities e.g. title bar created in tabactivities. how is it possible to reach the button in all of the sub activities??

```
public class tabActivity extends TabActivity  implements OnClickListener{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    c = this;
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.tabactivity);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Settings",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.preferences)).setContent(
                    new Intent(this, Settings.class)));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("About",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newspaper)).setContent(
                    new Intent(this, About.class)));
```

This is here where i initialize my tabs, and the custom title with buttons..

And in this class i would like to reach the buttons in the custom title.:

```
public class About extends Activity 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.about);

    ImageView imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Position);
    imag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("heeey");
        }
    });

}
```

The listener doesnt work??

Hooow is this possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class tabActivity extends TabActivity{ 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    c = this; 
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 

    setContentView(R.layout.tabactivity); 

    ImageView imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Position);         
    imag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         

    public void onClick(View v) {         
       tabActivity.listener.onClick(v);
    }         

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title); 

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Settings", 
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.preferences)).setContent( 
                new Intent(this, Settings.class))); 

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("About", 
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newspaper)).setContent( 
                new Intent(this, About.class))); 
}

public static void setListner(OnClickListener listener)
{
    tabActivity.listner = listener;
}
```

main activity does not implements eventListener

```
public class About extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{      
    @Override      
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)       
    {      
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      

        setContentView(R.layout.about);      

    });         

    public void onResume()
    {
        tabActivity.setListener(this);
    }


}
```

code goes like this. It's hard to explain

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of that? The event controll is available in main activity.

Comment: I recommend to set as a listener each activity when onTabChanged called. It will make possible to perform other actions each activity.

Comment: I need the listener in my sub activities.. Is that possible?? I know that i can listen to them in the tabActivity..

Comment: you can implement listener each activity like this. class AAA extends Activity implements MyListener > and override method and code what you want. and in onTabChanged() you can set each subactivity as a listener instead of previous one.

Comment: I posted another response. It is code for just understanding.